# Object returned by LINQ cannot assigned with object with same class

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, oop

I'm trying to assign object returned by Linq to new object with same class, example:

`object x = (object) y`

Actual code example:

```
public void update(Person person){
    //Persons is observable collection
    Person found = Persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == person.Id);
    found = person; //Persons not changing
}


Person newPerson = new Person(1, "Andy");
update(newPerson);
```

I've tried with cloning:

```
public void update(Person person){
    //Persons is observable collection
    Person found = Persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == person.Id);
    found = person.Clone(); // CLONING but Persons STILL NOT changing
}


Person newPerson = new Person(1, "Andy");
update(newPerson);
```

The Persons observablecollection variable remain unchanged. I cannot see whats wrong with the code, any suggestion?

Edit: sorry for wrong syntax earlier.

Comment: What's with the `function` keyword? Post your actual working code.

Comment: Are you trying to replace an object in an ObservableCollection?

Comment: I'm afraid you miss some basic c# knowledge. You only assign the `person` _refererence_ to your **local variable** `found`. That doesn't change the _instance_ you previously found in the `Persons` collection.

Comment: sorry everyone about the typo. @RenéVogt, sure, but how found.Name = person.Name works?

Comment: @tonywei yes, that would change the `Name` property of the instance you found in your collection.

Comment: @RenéVogt, so its impossible to do object=object returned by LINQ? okay then, so i just use found.Name = person.Name. thanks

Comment: @hatchet, my question already answered, but i'll look into it, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to *replace* a `Person` object in an `ObservableCollection<Person>` with another one, try this:

```
Person found = Persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == person.Id);
if(found != null)
{
    int index = Persons.IndexOf(found);
    Persons[index] = person;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The Persons observablecollection variable remain unchanged.

Uh, yeah, duh. You're not changing its reference or updating values inside it.

```
Person found = Persons.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == person.Id);
found = person; //not changing
```

You're setting the reference of `found` *to* the reference of `person`. So `person` won't change.

Say I did something like this:

```
void ModifyString(string input)
{
    string newValue = Database.GetNewValue();
    newValue = input;
}
```

No matter what I passed in, `input` would never change, either *inside* the method or *outside* the method (the instance used as the argument).

Are you sure you don't have your assignment backwards?

Comment: yes, i know that "person" wont change, but i want "Persons" with "s" letter in the end of it to change.

Comment: Then you should change Persons[x] to another Person object. See my answer for an example.